# Openshift Ruby Stuck at installing Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, openshift, bundler

I created a fresh new Ruby 2.0 cartridge, then start up a new Rails 4 project and push to it, but when installing the Gems via bundler, it is stuck forever at Installing nokogiri... Anyone encountered that before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, was using the Rails cartridge but it doesn't happen on the default template because it doesn't have any Gemfile dependency.

I noticed that nokogiri can only be installed on openshift with `--use-system-libraries` extra param like this:

`gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries`

However, prefixing

`bundle config --local build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries`

to the pre_build hook yields an error because we do not have permission to write to .bundle directory. How you can do it is run the `bundle config --local...` command in your local computer, it will generate a .bundle directory in your local project hierarchy, then add the file inside to your git and push it to openshift, the bundler install should run correctly now